# Why is promise resolving with undefined?

Tags: promise

```js
var firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve('first promise');
});

firstPromise.then(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('second promise');
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log('hello');
  });
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I know this is not the best way to write this promise chain, but I was wondering why the last `.then` executes at all. I'm not returning anything with `console.log('hello')`, so wouldn't the .then off of the second promise never resolve?

Comment: Returning nothing just means returning `undefined`. Also, your code would be much simpler if you did `Promise.resolve('first promise')` instead of using the `Promise` constructor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you've chained several promises together and one of your `.then()` handlers returns nothing.

This part:

```js
.then((result) => {
    console.log('hello');
    // since there is no return value here, 
    // the promise chain's resolved value becomes undefined
});
```

returns nothing which is essentially the same as `return undefined` and therefore the resolved value of the chain becomes `undefined`.

You can change it to this to preserve the resolved value:

```js
.then((result) => {
    console.log('hello');
    return result;         // preserve resolved value of the promise chain
});
```

Remember that the return value of every `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value of the chain going forward.  No return value makes the resolved value be `undefined`.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize there was an implicit return. Didn't make the connection that all js functions have this behavior.

Comment: This statement clears it up 'Remember that the return value of every .then() handler becomes ...'. Kudos

Comment: This is such a clear and well-written answer. I was really struggling to wrap my head around the `undefined` pattern with Promise chaining and you've helped me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your last .then is receiving the result created in your nested Promise, and, since you are not returning anything ( i.e. you are just doing console.log('hello') ) then result is undefined. You can see this behaviour if you actually return something :

```
    var firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve("first promise");
    });

    firstPromise
      .then(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          resolve("second promise");
        }).then(result => {
          console.log("hello");
          return "something";
        });
      })
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

this would output :

```
'hello'
'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call any number of `then` s after the resolve of promise.
in your case: **//1** resolved promise assigned to **//2** results
**//4** has no returns to work with. So, results are undefined.

```js
var firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('first promise');
});

firstPromise.then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('second promise');//1
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);//2
        console.log('hello');//3
    });
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);//4
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

if you have return something after **//3** result is assined by it.

```js
var firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('first promise');
});

firstPromise.then(() => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('second promise');//1
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);//2
        console.log('hello');//3
        return("test")
    });
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);//4
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```